# Manually add new column in Doctrine2 not working

Tags: doctrine-orm

I inherited a zend framework code with doctrine2.

I am trying to add a new column manually to no avail.

1) I create the last_viewed column in db which is dateTime format.

2) I added in the entity file

```or-tag-here
/**
 * @var datetime $lastViewed
 */
protected $last_viewed;

/**
 * Set lastViewed
 *
 * @param datetime $lastViewed
 */
public function setlastViewed($lastViewed) {
    $this->last_viewed = $last_viewed;
}

/**
 * Get lastViewed
 *
 * @return datetime
 */
public function gelastViewed() {
    return $this->last_viewed;
}
```

3) Updated the YML file

```
last_viewed:
  type: datetime
```

But when I try and retrive via

```or-tag-here
$user->gelastViewed()
```

I get an empty value.

Also when the entity proxy is generated I don't see the column name in the function "__sleep" rest all other columns are there.

Any suggestions as to how to add this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out cache was the culprit. Restarted Memcache and it works now !!!